# How can i connect and get the data of flbuilder beaver builder wordpress and gatsbyjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to connect gatsby and wordpress but not using only this package https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/ otherwise trying to customize or get the data of beaver builder fl-builder. Is it possible to get?

https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3591

I expect that someone has found a solution for writing the pages using flbuilder beaver builder and gatsby.

Comment: Did you see this comment? https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3591#issuecomment-414917600

Comment: Yeah but i see that something not works, it seems like i need customize the wordpress plugin source, i tried to do that but without results.

Comment: Can you add what you tried to the question?